# Is it possible to use different themes based on file type?

Tags: atom-editor

Is it possible to have themes run based on the type of document?

For example, I'd like to have one theme for .js, .html, another for .md files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**This is no longer the correct answer, please see the other answer for a package that allows you to do what the question asked. I tried to delete this answer, but can‘t do it, since it‘s the accepted answer at the moment.**

<strike>No, this is currently not possible.</strike>

<strike>Atom uses two themes: The UI Theme determines the overall layout of the editor, including tabs, the tree view and and all other visible areas - is this really what you want?</strike>

<strike>The Syntax Theme determines the colors used for displaying text and highlighting based on the syntax. There's currently no automatic way for switching the syntax theme based on the selected file's language.</strike>

<strike>Having said that, you could probably write a package to do that. Please be aware that switching between themes takes a couple of moments, I don't know how practical it would be to switch the whole theme based on the file type.</strike>

<strike>There's a couple of packages that switch between themes or to a random theme every couple of minutes or based on a keypress, you could probably use one of these as an example if you want to build your own:</strike>

- <strike>https://atom.io/packages/theme-roulette</strike>
- <strike>https://atom.io/packages/theme-switcher</strike>
- <strike>https://atom.io/packages/switcheroo</strike>

Comment: I've marked your answer as correct, because the answer to my question is no. However, part of your answer is incorrect, Atom uses 2 themes: "UI Theme (This styles the table, status bar, tree view, and dropdowns); and Syntax Theme (This styles the text inside the editor)" - taken from Themes page in Settings of Atom 0.135.0

Comment: Yes, that's true. Which one would you like to change based on the file type? The UI Theme, or the Syntax Theme? It wasn't clear from your question.

Comment: touché - by implication the editor theme. There is a package called [theme switcher](https://atom.io/packages/theme-switcher), which does what you propose, although it switchs on a key-press not on file type. Perhaps you could edit your answer to reflect our little conversation?

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect the different themes.

Comment: Picking this up 2 years later... but shouldn't CSS like this work for the basics? 

atom-text-editor.editor[data-grammar='less'] {
  background: red;
}

It doesn't - but shouldn't it?

Comment: [multi-theme-applicator](https://atom.io/packages/multi-theme-applicator) should change the answer to yes, no?

Comment: This answer isn't right anymore. There is a package you can use, called the [multi-theme-applicator](https://atom.io/packages/multi-theme-applicator)

Comment: Yes, that's why I updated the answer to refer to the other answer below. I can't delete my answer since it is the accepted answer, otherwise it wouldn't be here anymore...

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried multi-theme-applicator? It seems to work well for me! As long as you have atom > 1.13 it should work. Here are the links to the atom.io documentation for this package, as well as the github page.

https://atom.io/packages/multi-theme-applicator

https://github.com/vt5491/multi-theme-applicator

Comment: Multi theme applicator can apply different themes based on file type. Coul you please mark my answer as correct? The current accepted answer could mislead people into thinking this isn't possible.